# Prefer one record over anotherin a table where a specific column shows as not NULL for value (per ID)

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, lag, coalesce

Using a table MY_TABLE like this:

| ID | TYPE | START_ | END_ | LOADED | SOURCE_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | NULL | 5 | 2022-03-03 21:57:38.494 | '2022-03-03' |
| 1 | B | NULL | 7 | 2023-07-20 22:55:38.494 | '2023-07-20' |
| 1 | A | 5 | NULL | 2023-07-20 22:57:38.494 | '2023-07-20' |
| 1 | B | NULL | 7 | 2023-07-20 22:59:38.494 | '2023-07-20' |
| 4 | A | NULL | 20 | 2023-06-30 18:59:38.494 | '2023-06-30' |
| 4 | A | 20 | 17 | 2023-06-30 19:43:38.494 | '2023-06-30' |
| 5 | A | NULL | 32 | 2023-05-30 04:43:36.494 | '2023-05-30' |
| 5 | B | NULL | 48 | 2023-05-30 05:48:32.494 | '2023-05-30' |
| 7 | A | NULL | 32 | 2023-04-22 08:33:36.494 | '2023-04-22' |
| 7 | B | 10 | NULL | 2023-04-22 09:58:32.434 | '2023-04-22' |

I've gotten the latest changes per TYPE by doing

```
SELECT *
FROM MY_TABLE
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, TYPE ORDER BY SOURCE_DATE DESC) = 1;
```

Which results in a table like

| ID | TYPE | START_ | END_ | LOADED | SOURCE_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 5 | NULL | 2023-07-20 22:57:38.494 | '2023-07-20' |
| 1 | B | NULL | 7 | 2023-07-20 22:59:38.494 | '2023-07-20' |
| 4 | A | 20 | 17 | 2023-06-30 19:43:38.494 | '2023-06-30' |
| 5 | A | NULL | 32 | 2023-05-30 04:43:36.494 | '2023-05-30' |
| 5 | B | NULL | 48 | 2023-05-30 05:48:32.494 | '2023-05-30' |
| 7 | A | NULL | 32 | 2023-04-22 08:33:36.494 | '2023-04-22' |
| 7 | B | 10 | NULL | 2023-04-22 09:58:32.434 | '2023-04-22' |

I am trying to get a resulting table where per ID if TYPE A is present in the records for the ID and END_ is not NULL for TYPE A then prefer TYPE A's END_ for the ID, otherwise keep the END_ for TYPE B or if there is just one record for the ID then keep the END_. I am essentially trying to end up with a table like

| ID | TYPE | START_ | END_ | SOURCE_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | B | NULL | 7 | '2023-07-20' |
| 4 | A | 20 | 17 | '2023-06-30' |
| 5 | A | NULL | 32 | '2023-05-30' |
| 7 | A | NULL | 32 | '2023-04-22' |

(the LOADED column is not neeeded in my final result/output table) Is there a way I can do this? I've tried:

```
WITH GET_LATEST_CHANGES AS (SELECT *
FROM MY_TABLE
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, TYPE ORDER BY SOURCE_DATE DESC) = 1
)
SELECT ID, TYPE, START_, END_, SOURCE_DATE,
     CASE 
        WHEN TYPE <> LAG(TYPE, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY SOURCE_DATE) AND TYPE = 'A' AND END_ IS NULL THEN COALESCE(LAG(END_, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY SOURCE_DATE), END_)
        WHEN TYPE <> LAG(TYPE, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY SOURCE_DATE) AND TYPE = 'A' AND END_ IS NOT NULL THEN COALESCE(END_, LAG(END_, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY SOURCE_DATE))
        ELSE END_
     END AS END_2
FROM GET_LATEST_CHANGES;
```

However this method seems a bit complex and I am also having trouble with a case like ID 5 where the END_ value for both TYPE A and B are filled and how to prefer TYPE A record over B in this case. Thanks!

Comment: What's the actual table name? Surely not my_table. And do you have a secondary table having unique values for ID?

Comment: Yes the table name for this example is MY_TABLE and I'm not sure what you mean by a secondary table, I just have this one table

Comment: Ah I felt your prior question was over compressed.

Answer (score 0):

This produces nearly your desired output, but does better with null values for the start column (you can adjust the `coalesce` logic if needed).

```sql
create table my_table(
    id int not null,
    type char(1) not null,
    start_ int,
    end_ int,
    loaded timestamp not null,
    source_date date not null
);

insert into my_table(id, type, start_, end_, loaded, source_date) values
(1, 'A', NULL,    5, '2022-03-03 21:57:38.494', '2022-03-03'),
(1, 'B', NULL,    7, '2023-07-20 22:55:38.494', '2023-07-20'),
(1, 'A',    5, NULL, '2023-07-20 22:57:38.494', '2023-07-20'),
(1, 'B', NULL,    7, '2023-07-20 22:59:38.494', '2023-07-20'),
(4, 'A', NULL,   20, '2023-06-30 18:59:38.494', '2023-06-30'),
(4, 'A',   20,   17, '2023-06-30 19:43:38.494', '2023-06-30'),
(5, 'A', NULL,   32, '2023-05-30 04:43:36.494', '2023-05-30'),
(5, 'B', NULL,   48, '2023-05-30 05:48:32.494', '2023-05-30'),
(7, 'A', NULL,   32, '2023-04-22 08:33:36.494', '2023-04-22'),
(7, 'B',   10, NULL, '2023-04-22 09:58:32.434', '2023-04-22');

with grouped as (
    select distinct on (id, type) id, type, start_, end_, source_date
    from my_table
    order by id, type, source_date desc
)
select coalesce(type_a.id, type_b.id) as id,
    case when type_a.end_ is not null then type_a.type else type_b.type end as type,
    coalesce(type_a.start_, type_b.start_) as start,
    coalesce(type_a.end_, type_b.end_) as end,
    case when type_a.end_ is not null then type_a.source_date else type_b.source_date end as source_date
from grouped as type_a
full outer join grouped as type_b on type_a.id = type_b.id
                                 and type_a.type <> type_b.type
where (type_a.type is null or type_a.type = 'A')
  and (type_b.type is null or type_b.type = 'B');
```

```
id  type    start   end     source_date
1   B       5   7   2023-07-20
4   A       20  17  2023-06-30
5   A   null    32  2023-05-30
7   A       10  32  2023-04-22
```

Answer (score 0):

The first to note, is your initial QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER has instability, and you need add another term to sort between items that has the some `SORUCE DATE` as you can see you ID 4 both has the same value, so you will get random results with your current code. I choose you use LOADED DESC also:

```
select *
from my_table
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, TYPE 
        ORDER BY SOURCE_DATE DESC, loaded DESC) = 1
```

if we push that into a cte (or a sub-select can be used), we are want to rank the four types of lines outputted by the above filter:

```
select *
    ,case
        when type = 'A' and end_ is not null then 4
        when type = 'B' and end_ is not null then 3
        when type = 'A' and end_ is null then 2
        when type = 'B' and end_ is null then 1
    end as type_rank
from last_per_id_type_filter
```

which gives:

[image]

we can make that case simpler, because the last is just the else, and the third    has to be null, so it could be written:

```
    ,case
        when type = 'A' and end_ is not null then 4
        when type = 'B' and end_ is not null then 3
        when type = 'A' then 2
        else 1
    end as type_rank
```

Also if you like very tight SQL this could be compressed into an IFF and two NVL2

```
,iff(type = 'A', NVL2(end_,4,2), NVL2(end_,3,1)) as type_rank
```

but again, being more explicate does not really hurt, and helps other reads to know what was intended.

so now we can add another QUALIFY this time using a window frame MAX:

```
WITH last_per_id_type_filter as (
    select *
    from my_table
    QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, TYPE 
        ORDER BY SOURCE_DATE DESC, loaded DESC) = 1
)
select *
    ,case
        when type = 'A' and end_ is not null then 4
        when type = 'B' and end_ is not null then 3
        when type = 'A' and end_ is null then 2
        when type = 'B' and end_ is null then 1
    end as type_rank
from last_per_id_type_filter
QUALIFY max(type_rank) over (partition by id) = type_rank
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

and the `type_rank` can be dropped by using the compact form of the type rank:

```
QUALIFY max(iff(type = 'A', NVL2(end_,4,2), NVL2(end_,3,1))) over (partition by id) = iff(type = 'A', NVL2(end_,4,2), NVL2(end_,3,1))
```

or by adding a exclude on a sub-select (or CTE):

```
select * exclude (type_rank) from (
    select *
       ,iff(type = 'A', NVL2(end_,4,2), NVL2(end_,3,1)) as type_rank
    from last_per_id_type_filter
    QUALIFY max(type_rank) over (partition by id) = type_rank
)
```